# css text element with line behind text on the right

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-class, heading

How to make this headline in the css? Preferably without flexbox.

Image:
[image: open image]

Comment: image: http://polariton.ad-l.ink/8zKchQX6k/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I would expect you to put some code and show us what you have tried, the following is one way to do it.

Essentially you create an `after` pseudo element, give it a 1px height and a background color of your choice. Then you position it absolutely within it's parent heading element with a lower z-index.

There are possibly better ways of doing it, with flexbox too but I didn't mention that as per the question.

```css
.with-line {
  position: relative;
}
.with-line span {
  /*change it to match whatever background color you want.*/
  background: white;
  
}
.with-line:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  background: #666;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="with-line"><span>Hello</span></h1>
```

Comment: Please do not answer this sort of questions. Questions like this are considered to be low-quality and should be closed to keep SOF standards up and running

Comment: Agreed. I downvoted it myself but somehow I just felt like answering in case the OP edits the question to make it better. My bad. Should I delete the answer?

Comment: That would be nice if you keep this for future.